# Tensorflow: export model processing time

Tags: python, tensorflow, time

Is there a way to **export** the **time** that a **Tensorflow model** took processing?

I would like to include it in a script that has a `for` loop that tests different model settings to optimize accuracy to a specific model. It would be very useful to know/limit the time it took to process (so that I can let it run during the night and exclude values that take too much processing time in further tests).
I can already do it *manually* using `TensorBoard` but it gets a little hard to do when I want to test way more than 50 different models... It would be great to include it on the `script` and make it *automatically*.
Thanks for the help!

```
#The model uses tf.keras.models.Sequential

#Examples of variables
dense_layers =  [3, 4, 5]
layer_size =    [32, 64, 128]

for d in dense_layers:
    for s in layer_size:
        #Run model and get results to append on a list
```

PS: Sorry if this is explained somewhere else or is a duplicate but Tensorflow's web page is all but beginner-friendly and when I searched the topic here I only found people complaining about slow iterations on their scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want to exclude configurations from your results that took too long to train you can easily time the training process using the `time` module in python. Then only save the configurations if they take less than a given threshold time.

```
import time
#The model uses tf.keras.models.Sequential

#Examples of variables
dense_layers =  [3, 4, 5]
layer_size =    [32, 64, 128]

time_threshold = 60*60*0.5 # upper time limit in seconds (example 30 mins)
successful_configurations = []

for d in dense_layers:
    for s in layer_size:
        tic = time.time()
        #Run model and get results to append on a list
        toc = time.time()
        execution_time = toc-tic

        if execution_time<time_threshold:
            config = {'accuracy': test_accuracy, 
                      'run_time': execution_time, 
                      'dense_layers': d,
                      'layer_size': s}

            successful_configurations.append(cofig)
```

You can include any of the model settings in the `config` dictionary that is construed inside the if the time is sufficiently low. Here I have included `test_accuracy` which would need to be returned by your `#Run model and get results to append on a list` step.

No need to export anything.